# React native: Fastlane build Ios fail after upgrading version project

Tags: react-native, fastlane, fastlane-gym

My fastlane in react native ran perfectly when it was on version 0.66.1, but after I upgrade to 0.70.6, when build iOS app through fastlane it give me this error [image].

Have anyone face this issue? Please help me.